# invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have this in my header

```
struct str_list_element_struct
{
    char* string;
    struct str_list_element_struct* next;
};
typedef struct str_list_element_scruct str_list_element;
typedef str_list_element* str_list;
```

and get this error when I try to `sizeof` it

> str_list.c:21: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'str_list_element'

How is my type "*incomplete*"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've misspelled "str_list_element_struct" as "str_list_element_**scruct**" in the typedef.

Comment: How on earth did you spot that so quickly? I've been over those words a hundred times and missed it :-)